Upgrading to 24.04 issues
I have a Dell Precision 3430 that I purchased several years ago from Dell preloaded with Ubuntu. It's been a great machine until recently when I tried to upgrade from 22.04 LTS to 24.04 LTS. Every upgrade attempt fals saying I may have a network issue which I don't. Furthermore, the roll back seems to have left something corrupted as I experience repeated stalled processes. I decided it was time to explore Mint but can't figure out how to boot to a USB thumb drive. I can't find an option in the POST to point the boot to an external device or any kind of 'manual' on how to use the POST options. So guess my question is three parts: any way to 'clean up' my current Ubuntu installation either the current version or through an upgrade to 24.04, how to boot to a thumb drive, and how to use the POST menu options.

I believe pre-installed Ubuntu has a partition with an ISO or installer and a customized grub to boot that ISO to reinstall/recovery system. If upgrading, you do not need that, but may be a good idea to backup that partition and grub entry. F12 will give you a UEFI/BIOS boot menu. My Dell says "BIOS" but is UEFI only. Older Dell's often needed Legacy/CMS/BIOS turned on, but then you still boot in UEFI mode. I have preferred new installs to just clean up built up "cruft", but many do upgrades without issues. Is Secure boot on? Or USB boot allowed type setting?

Please fresh install Ubuntu 24.04. Download Ubuntu ISO and flash it onto a USB

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Thanks for the suggestions. My main issue is how to boot to a USB thumb drive. The BIOS menu doesn't included that option and from what I can tell only allows booting from the fixed drive or a network drive (which, of course, I don't have). I have already decided if I save this machine I was going to try a fresh install and actually going to switch to Mint. I HATE Snap on Ubuntu for one thing. So anyone know how to use the UEFI menu to switch to booting from a USB drive first??

Assuming you have correctly installed the Ubuntu 22.04 .iso file to your USB flash drive, you don't have to rummage around in the UEFI settings in order to boot from it.
With your machine turned off, plug the flash drive into a USB port and power on. As soon as the Dell logo comes up, hit the F12 key. That should bring up a boot menu which should include the flash drive option. Arrow down to it and hit enter.

Nope. I bought my Dell several years ago with the latest Ubuntu preinstalled at the factory and have updated it faithfully ever since. All was well until I attempted the 24.04 update. That failed and ever since the update routine did the rollback to 22.04 I've had issues. So I tried to boot to a USB flash drive from UEFI and it wouldn't offer a boot to anything but the hard drive or the network. So that's where I am...
